# Does AWS Application Load Balancer Support TLS 1.3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl

I am Trying To Search On google but I can not finding any A.W.S documentation regarding TLS 1.3

Comment: https://www.repost.aws/questions/QUaZmXt5NPRpKKkTU7Q0Qq1Q/how-to-enable-tls-v-1-3-in-alb

Answer (score 25):

TLS 1.3 support in the Network Load Balancer has just been [announced](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/10/aws-network-load-balancer-supports-tls-1-3/), so I think it's reasonable to expect that the [new TLS 1.3 policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/create-tls-listener.html), such as `ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS13-1-2-2021-06`, will also be available on Application Load Balancers in a few weeks.

**Update 2023-03-23**: turned out to be more than a few weeks, but it's been [announced](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/03/application-load-balancer-tls-1-3/) today. The available policies, e.g. `ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS13-1-2-2021-06` are documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/create-https-listener.html#describe-ssl-policies).

Comment: So far this has not happened.  Currently the latest policy available for an Application Load Balancer is `ELBSecurityPolicy-FS-1-2-Res-2020-10`.

Comment: Still no love from AWS ALB in January 2022 :(

Comment: And now April 2022 :(

Comment: May 2022, Still waiting,

Comment: As at 9 Jun, still negative.

Comment: 29th June 2022, big nope

Comment: 15th July 2022, still nope!

Comment: 1st August 2022, still nope.

Comment: 14 August 2022, still nope.

Comment: 1st September 2022, and guess what? Still nope

Comment: 11th September 2022, still nope :(

Comment: Dear diary, it is 28th day of September today. Still no sign of TLS 1.3 support.

Comment: 25th October 2022. Still nope.

Comment: 18th November 2022, nnnada

Comment: 14 December 2022, йок

Comment: 28th December 2022, not working.

Comment: Happy New Year 2023! It's...a nope, still :[

Comment: Happy Valentines day!
Still nope!

Comment: Indeed, Happy Valentine's day!  It's ... a nope, still :{

Comment: Is there anything similar to Cloudfront TLSv1.2_2021 for ALB?

Comment: Looks like it's been enabled but not documented. ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS13-1-2-2021-06 exists now

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/03/application-load-balancer-tls-1-3/ it is now supported!

Answer (score 21):

It does not support it. The supported versions are listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/create-https-listener.html#tls-security-policies).

Answer (score 11):

I submitted a feature request in AWS support center today. Excerpt from the response:

> I have taken a look internally and can see that we have an existing
> feature request for ALB to support TLS 1.3, which is a very popular
> request among our customers. Unfortunately, as the development process
> is internal, i wouldn't be able to provide you with an ETA on when ALB
> support for TLS 1.3 will be implemented at this time. Please be
> assured, that I have added your voice to this feature request so that
> this case can be used as supporting evidence for this feature and so
> it can gain priority among the internal team responsible for
> development.

Comment: Got the same answer today, it's a highly requested feature, yada-yada.

Comment: Not sure if Amazon updates their ticket but this now exists! ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS13-1-2-2021-06 there are no docs currently. And I've not seen it in cdk yet

Answer (score 3):

A few days ago, ALB started supporting TLS1.3!
The documentation has not been updated, but you can use the security policy implemented in NLB, **ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS13-1-2-2021-06**!

[ALB Security Policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uW3ud.png)

Answer (score 2):

[Application Load Balancer now supports TLS 1.3](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/03/application-load-balancer-tls-1-3/) announced by AWS on Mar 22, 2023.

> TLS 1.3 is available on ALBs in all commercial AWS Regions, AWS GovCloud (US) Regions and AWS Outposts

TLS 1.3 security policies of ALB could be found in the [ALB Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/create-https-listener.html#tls13-security-policies) and the recommended policy is `ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS13-1-2-2021-06`

Comment: Finally! Boom...